# Gather certain variables in TF2 functional APIs

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

In TF-1.0, variables are managed by names, and when we want use a set of variables, we add them to a collection.

TF-2.0/Keras models are object-oriented. Variables are managed by Keras.Layer as its property, like "trainable_weights".

When I use functional API for building a model, what's the propery way to modify a set of certain variables. eg. weights of some blocks in the network.

More clear,

```py
def block(x):
   hierarchy1
     ...
     hierarchy2
     ...
        custom-layer

   return out 

inputs = Input(shape=(100,))
x = block(inputs)
x = block(x)
....
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
```

how could I get variables of all custom-layers with model

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question. As you said, you can access the weights of a layer through its properties if you want to set new values for them.

Comment: In the training loop, what i have is the whole model, not certain layers. In TF1.0, I can add those layers to a global collection, which is deprecated in TF2. how can i get the collection with keras functional APIs. eg. all variables of certain custom layers.

Comment: You could go through the `.layers` of the model and get those of the type you need checking with `isinstance`, if that works for you. If you want a specific set of arbitrary layers, then you will need to keep track of that somewhere. You could e.g. have `model.my_new_property = [lyr1, lyr2]`, or [subclass `Model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#the_model_class) for that purpose, or use some global storage. In the end, that is equivalent to what graph collections were.